# Location of Extension Manifest [package.json] file on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[I use macOS]

I have an extension called Code Runner:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner
All I want to do is clear output everytime I execute some C++.So I found this command online:

```json
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true
```

But I am unable to fund where to enter it.I think its the package.json file,but I am unable to located.This is very trivial but its really annoying me!

Answer (score 0):

It's a [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) (`settings.json`), there's no need to change the extension's manifest.

Note that these days, VSCode opens the settings with a UI by default rather than raw JSON (which likely wasn't the case when Code Runner's readme was written).

Comment: I already figured it out.Can believe I wasted an hour on it :( .